# Create a opcode database

Tags: python, c, reverse-engineering

I became more interested in reversing binaries ever since the NSA released Ghidra, which has a built-in feature that produces pseudo C-code from the disassembly of binary.

I had the idea to build an opcode database with the corresponding assembly and C code. I want to write a tool that can dump a binary like readelf and objdump, extract the symbols and functions from a C source file, and bring it all together

So, to make it more clearly, lets take one example.

We download the vim-source on an ubuntu system. We compile it using ./configure and ./make. When the binary is ready, we start our tool, extract the opcodes of the symbols, create assembler-code from the code, extract the function and function-body of the .c-file, put it all together and write this into a database.

So the database should contain the following stuff:

c-function sourcecode like

```
int main()
{ 
  return 0; 
}
```

The assembler may look like:

```
push rbp
mov rbp, rsp
...
ret
```

and the opcode-section like:

```
55 48 89 e5 89 7d ec 89 75 ...
```

So my question is... Would it make sense to catalogue these data to use this maybe as a plugin in a disassembler? The idea was that a plugin can post the opcodes to a webservice and get possible c-sources back. So a decompiler may use this to kick away the pseudo-code and replace this with realworld-code examples.

I know that its not that easy like this because we have different compilers, architectures, versions, endianes and so on. But all in all, with a big database containing opcodes for each architecture/version/compiler it should be possible to make it more easy to reverse-engineer unknown binaries.

I put the code for this together the yesterday, but i am unsure if this would be helpful to extend disassemblers.

To get a feeling for it, here is a example of a small calc-tool which i wrote in c and the output of my tool yet:

```
|==================================================================|
| Adress             | Function                       | Size       |
|====================|================================|============|
| 0x0000000000000679 | add                            | 33         |
|==================================================================|
| OPCode                                                           |
|==================================================================|
| 55 48 89 e5 89 7d ec 89 75 e8 c7 45 fc 00 00 00 00 8b 55 ec 8b   |
| 45 e8 01 d0 89 45 fc 8b 45 fc 5d c3                              |
|==================================================================|
| Assembler                                                        |
|==================================================================|
| 0x1000  : push        rbp                                |
| 0x1001  : mov         rbp, rsp                           |
| 0x1004  : mov         dword ptr [rbp - 0x14], edi        |
| 0x1007  : mov         dword ptr [rbp - 0x18], esi        |
| 0x100a  : mov         dword ptr [rbp - 4], 0             |
| 0x1011  : mov         edx, dword ptr [rbp - 0x14]        |
| 0x1014  : mov         eax, dword ptr [rbp - 0x18]        |
| 0x1017  : add         eax, edx                           |
| 0x1019  : mov         dword ptr [rbp - 4], eax           |
| 0x101c  : mov         eax, dword ptr [rbp - 4]           |
| 0x101f  : pop         rbp                                |
| 0x1020  : ret                                            |
|==================================================================|
| Source                                                           |
|==================================================================|
| int add(int a, int b)                                            |
| {                                                                |
|   int c = 0;                                                      |
|   c = a + b;                                                      |
|   return c;                                                       |
| }                                                                |
|                                                                  |
|==================================================================|
```

Comment: Not sure what the question is here. Several people/companies have produced disassemblers, with varying degrees of success. If you want to be the next one to give it a try, go for it.

Comment: Excellent problem.But: hard. Please continue. (have you  investigated self-modifying code  yet?)

Comment: No, i have not done this yet. Do you have any code examples for this so that i can work with this?

Answer (score 0):

Such opcode databases are already implemented in various compilers that compile to native code.

For example, LLVM has such databases in form of TableGen language files. Backend disassemblers are mostly auto-generated from these descriptions. Take a look at [Sparc backend](https://github.com/llvm-mirror/llvm/blob/master/lib/Target/Sparc/SparcInstrInfo.td#L649), for instance.

Projects like [Capstone Disassembler](http://www.capstone-engine.org/) use LLVM to disassemble code for various CPUs.